# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TYPE_HIERARCHY_AND_ENCLOSING_CLASSES

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, upgrade

When I tried upgrading the Spring boot version to 2.7.5 and spring framework dependencies version to 6.0.10 , as I have upgraded the java version to JDK 17, I am getting the following error while running the application.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TYPE_HIERARCHY_AND_ENCLOSING_CLASSES at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.isConstructorBindingAnnotatedType(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:89) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
```

Please, let me know what can I try to resolve this issue.

I tried using the lower version of spring framework dependencies. Still no luck.

Comment: I am also getting for spring boot version 2.7.16, earlier wasn't, strange.

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure that you do not have any old spring-boot (2.x) and spring (5.x) on class-path. I had the same issue, but after defining explicit version of spring-boot and spring in build.gradle

```
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:$springBootVersion",
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:$springBootVersion",
"org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion",
"org.springframework:spring-tx:$springVersion",
```

Problem disappeared.

Spring 5.x has field SearchStrategy.TYPE_HIERARCHY_AND_ENCLOSING_CLASSES, where Spring 6.x don't.

That's why I guess, you have still Spring 5.x on the classpath